# To display manager details if more than one manager is from same city

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table `manager(managerid, name, address, city, phone)`. I have got to display the city, name and phone details if more than one manager is from the same city.
My code is:

```sql
  select m.city, m.name, m.phone
    from manager m
group by m.name
  having count(m.city) > 1;
```

But this shows me an error in the first line saying "not a group by expression".
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method uses `exists`:

```
select m.*
from manager m 
where exists (select 1
              from manager m2
              where m2.city = m.city and m2.managerid <> m.managerid
             );
```

You can also use `count()` as a *window* function:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*, count(*) over (partition by city) as cnt_city
      from manager m
     ) m
where cnt_city > 1;
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a ton! But would you mind if I ask for the explanation of the second piece of code?

Comment: @yaminir . . . It uses a window function (which Oracle calls analytic functions).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT city, managerid
FROM manager
WHERE city IN (
SELECT city
FROM manager
GROUP BY city
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).